# Entity Framework: Select null or value

Tags: entity-framework, select, null, coalesce

I'm searching to write with Entity Framework a select query which columns can be null or contain a value.

SQL Example:

```
select * from table
where column_1 is null or colummn_1 = 2
and column_2 is null or colummn_2 = 89
and column_3 is null or colummn_3 = 288;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you forgot to put `()` around your conditions. `and` binds at a higher precedence than `or`. it's running as `(column1 is null) OR (column_1 = 2 AND column 2 is null) OR (column2 = 89 AND column3 is null) or (column_3=288)`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
var result = repository.GetAll().Where(m => (m.column_1 == null || m.colummn_1 = 2) && etc)
```